# What coil-like components are these?

Tags: components, identification

What kind of components are these?

They do not have any marking, one is bigger than the other.
Both have 4 pins, and 4 coils.

They come from an old Philips CRT.

[image]

Comment: These are common-mode chockes. They're 2 inductors which are magnetically coupled. Yes, that makes them a transformer as well ! You could use them as a transformer as well. But they're only 1:1 transformers so that limits the applications. These are used to block high-frequency signals from getting to the mains connection for example. You see them mainly in switcher mode mains power supplies.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie -- make that an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ... thanks again (if you want get points, put it in an answer) :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are common-mode chokes. They're 2 inductors which are magnetically coupled.

[image]

Yes, that makes them a transformer as well !
And you could use them as a transformer. But they're only 1:1 transformers so that limits the applications.

These are used to block high-frequency (common mode) signals from getting to the mains connection for example. You see them mainly in switcher mode mains power supplies